# How to use a COUNTIF while simultaneously grouping duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

So I have the following table

[image: Sample table]

I'm trying to create a summary in another tab that counts the number of codes by Phase as well as the number of Platforms. For the number of codes, I'm able to use a COUNTIF easily, but for number of platforms, a COUNTIF doesn't work, because I don't want to count A's, B's etc. twice -- instead, I'd like the formula to give me a count of unique platforms within each phase.

My summary table structure is as follows, but I can't figure out how to write a formula to count the number of unique platforms per phase.

[image: summary table]

Some caveats.

- I don't want to do this through a pivot table
- Even though the platforms appear to run from A-F this is only a representation. My real dataset has a large number of platforms and I can't pre-define these as arguments in the formula

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Professional Plus 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have Excel 2016, you can use Power Query for this.

It will work well on large datasets with many unique values and won't involve lots of expensive array formulas.

Select a cell in your table of data and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to convert it to a Table.

Then use 'Data>Get Data>From Table'. Click OK on the dialog. The Power Query Window will open.

I created dummy data that has Codes, Platform and Phase, like this:

[image]

First, use 'Home>Group By', and configure it like this:

[image]

This will give you count of codes by Phase and Platform. Now use Group By again and configure it like this:

[image]

This should give the results you need. Now use 'Home>Close & Load' to get the data into your workbook:

[image]

When new data are added to your source table, you can simply right-click the query result in the workbook and choose 'Refresh':

[image]

EDIT:

It may be useful to note that by using Power Query, you can add other aggregations of your Volume column, such as Phase Volume, Phase Average Volume, Platform Average Volume, that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks so much. This has just opened up a world for me because I wasn't even aware of the Power Query Editor. I've managed to aggregate the info like I wanted.